# EF CTP 4 Database name configuration

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first

For sample I'm using this connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="PicturesDatabase" 
         connectionString=" Server=.;
                            Database=SomeprojectDatabase;
                            Trusted_Connection=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<../>
```

And then I use it in Application_Start() :

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory =
    new SqlConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["PicturesDatabase"].ConnectionString);
```

And in my database I get this really strange new Database :
**MyAppNamespace.Models.PicturesCatalog**
with two tables **dbo.EdmMetadata** and **dbo.Pictures**

Tables are fine, but why doesn't it create a new database named **PicturesDatabase** (as in connection string) with those tables ?

I've tried dropping this table few times, I did try creating PicturesDatabase and using it... but it still generates this  MyAppNamespace.Models.PicturesCatalog. What is the problem with it ? And how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory` is not meant to use in this way. This connection factory includes a constructor that allows us to override *pieces* of the final connection sting, such as username, password and server and not the whole thing. 

For example, we can change the Database Server like this:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = 
        new SqlConnectionFactory("Server=MyDatabaseServer");
```

What you try to do here can be easily accomplished by providing a connection string in your app.config that *matches* the name of your DbContext - I assume it's *PicturesCatalog*:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="PicturesCatalog" connectionString="data source=.; 
        Initial Catalog=PicturesDatabase; Trusted_Connection=True;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```